# Prevent Scrolling in VueJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vue-component, vue-cli

I am trying to prevent scrolling only when the lightbox component is open, but cannot seem to do so. I hope to not use any outside libraries or plug-ins to do this.

My App.vue contains the "LightBox" component, so I am assuming the prevent scrolling function should live in the App.vue as well.
App.vue snippet:

```
<template>
  <div class="SocialAlbumWidget">
    <div v-if="isModalVisible && media[activeIndex]">
      <LightBox
        ...
      />
```

I currently have a "showModal ()" function in the "methods" section, so was thinking of passing that through another function.

Methods:

```
mothods: {
...
showModal () {
  this.isModalVisible = true
},
closeModal () {
  this.isModalVisible = false
}
```

I expect the body to have scroll when the"Lightbox" component is closed and disabled when the "Lightbox" component is open. Thanks! Let me know what other code would be useful.

Comment: Post your `methods` object please

Comment: https://codepen.io/whatupnewyork/pen/gNRLgd?editors=1010

Comment: @Charlie I just updated it as you can see. In the meanwhile, I will look through the pen you just commented.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use a watcher to react to changes in `isModalVisible` and disable the scrolling function by using `style="overflow: hidden"`.

Something along these lines:

```
// HTML
<btn @click="dialog = !dialog" >Click Me </btn>

// JS
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      dialog: false,
    }
  },
  watch: {
    isModalVisible: function() {
      if(this.isModalVisible){
        document.documentElement.style.overflow = 'hidden'
        return
      }

      document.documentElement.style.overflow = 'auto'
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Syntax Error: SyntaxError: /Users/angello.lazar/Desktop/sdc-social-album-widget/src/App.vue: Unexpected token, expected "," (128:35)

  126 |   },
  127 |   watch: {
> 128 |     isModalVisible: preventScroll(){

Comment: That makes sense - thanks. But, not sure why I am receiving this error...

Comment: Figured it out! Thanks for the help!

Comment: thats not work on ios devices. U need fixed content and wach page scroll posotion, then add negative position top to your fixed wrap. after, when scroll turn on, u need scrollTop() on js to prev position.

Answer (score 18):

Prevent scrolling events on `LightBox` **modal** itself -

```html
<LightBox
 @wheel.prevent
 @touchmove.prevent
 @scroll.prevent
/>
```

---

style `overflow: hidden` might create some concerns.

such as;

- Visibility of scrollbar
- UI bounce `w.e.f` overflow toggle

Comment: @touchmove.prevent worked for me in mobile. I liked it

Comment: This doesn't seem to prevent dragging the scroll bars.

Comment: @killjoy does the Modal has background overlay?